# how to allow null in datefield in django views and model?

Tags: django, python-2.7, datetime, django-models, django-views

My code is:

```
In model:
claimed_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

In view:
claim_date = request.POST.get('date_totclaimfee','')
```

it shows error  :

[u"'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

```
All fields in views.py:

shoes_date = request.POST.get('date_shoesfee','')
vvn_receipt = request.POST.get('bill_vvnfee','')
vvn_fees = request.POST.get(str(c)+'c_vvnfee','')
vvn_date = request.POST.get('date_vvnfee',''))

mODEL.PY:
shoes_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
vvn_receipt = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True,blank=True)
vvn_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,)
vvn_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
claimed_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
claim_date = request.POST.get('date_totclaimfee', None)
```

Comment: let me try,please wait,i was trying continually from 3 hours

Comment: please, post you entire view code... maybe it helps me to suggest another solution...

Comment: IS THIS OK OR NEED FULL?

Comment: please, post the code that actually creates the instance of the model.

Comment: BUT WHERE? ITS TO LONG,CONTAINING 50 FIELDS,CAN I MAIL U? PLEASE

Comment: Its solve by the help of  suselrd, its change in instance when we assign with our variable, example: SomeDate = date or None